# rpy2 in python SyntaxError: invalid syntax for as.ape.AAbin

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

Im using rpy2 package in python. It's a package for R programming via python.  when i use 'as' function in python it consider it a syntax error. It works fine in R. I imported all necessary packages. Is there any command to replace as.apes.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importrcode
     utils = importr('utils')
     utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
     base = importr('base')
     methods= importr('methods')
     packnames = ('ape', 'aphid','methods')
     apes= importr("ape")
     g1 = as.apes.AAbin("EL---DSD-ILPELLATLARTHDLNK----VGPAHYDLFAKVLM")
```

> g1 = as.apes.AAbin("EL---DSD-ILPELLATLARTHDLNK----VGPAHYDLFAKVLM")
>             ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `as` is a keyword. There shouldn't be modules that use it as a name

Comment: There _is_ no `as` function in Python. Plus, you're not even trying to use it as a function in the first place, you're trying to use it as an object or module or some other kind of namespace. So, it's not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can get rid of the `SyntaxError` by just not using the `as` keyword as if it were a namespace, but that probably isn't doing to actually fix your code, since presumably there's something you need to do there with some object.

Comment: @ ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000  yes, `as` is a keyword. That what cause the problem. Its important to have it  here:`g1 = as.apes.AAbin("EL---DSD-ILPELLATLARTHDLNK----VGPAHYDLFAKVLM")` .

Comment: @abarnert yes i can't delete it's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved! I changed the whole way of calling R in python. I used wrapping,I used my whole R script as follows:

```
 from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage

string = """

    #paste your script here
    """

    powerpack = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(string, "powerpack")
```

refer to the[package documentation](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-r-packages) for further details.